# Android - Is video file encryption/decryption effects its quality?

Tags: java, android, encryption

I have a Video file of 700 mb, For security reason, I want to encrypt it and place into my SDcard. Then I want to play it by decrypting. Is it feasible by encryption/decryption techinque? Is the encryption/decryption will effect/reduce the video quality.
What will the better approach for it? If any good algorithms in Java please suggest.

I have tried some algorithm which is capable of encrypting but fail to decrypt.

**Edit:**
Also how can I secure video file and avoid being transmitted.

Cheers

Comment: You have achieved for this one? Currently I'm try like this, same as what you try this one. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Encryption/Decryption is lossless, otherwise you could not use it. So no, the video will be exactly the same, datawise. You are probably confusing it with compression.
2. It will effect playback quality. I don't think its feasible to decrpyt a video file on the fly on a mobile phone without lag when playing it.
3. If you can decrypt it on the phone, your approach is not able to secure your video.

The real question is, why do you want to encrypt a video file? If you can play it, you can rip it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, can you suggest is there any good way to secure my video file and avoid it to get transmitted.